# Home entertainment/DVR solutions

Tags: software-recommendation, tv

I'm setting up a home entertainment computer that will be taking in video input via cable and displaying recorded tv, DVDs, live tv, as well as playing music and movies via HDMI to a TV. What Media Center solutions exist for Ubuntu?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is some of my preferred apps.

**[1) VLC](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/)**  - [install](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/vlc/)

I included this app because you can use it to manage your audio and it can play *almost* every video formats out there. It is light on the system, simple, and has so many features (see [this](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/6-cool-vlc-tips-tricks/) for example).

[image]

**[2) Enna](http://enna.geexbox.org/)**  - [install](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/enna/)

Enna is beatyful. It shows the weather and besides audio, photo and video, it supports bookstore.

[image]

**[3) XBMC](http://xbmc.org/about/)**    - [install](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/xbmc/)`

It is easy to use, support audio, pictures, video, and is "skinnable". See Aeon skin next.

[image]

**[4) Boxee](http://www.boxee.tv/)**    - [To install you will have to sign up](http://www.boxee.tv/signup)
It is not so eye candy, but it is functional, support TV shows and has some Premium payable features.

[image]

**[5) Miro](http://www.getmiro.com/)**    - [install](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/miro/)

Support for download from torrent and youtube.

[image]

**[6) Freevo](http://freevo.sourceforge.net/)**    - [install](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/freevo/)

Support for music, photos, videos and games.

[image]

**[7) MythTv](http://www.mythtv.org)**    - [install](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/mythtv)

Can record videos for you.

[image]

**[8) LinuxMCE](http://www.linuxmce.com/)**    - [To install you will have to download a binary package](http://www.linuxmce.com/index.php/download)

It has others features like controls over your home lights, doors, security, etc.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As Aenima99x stated, [XMBC](http://xbmc.org/) which is a complete home theater solution with great themes, plugins, massive media capabilites, and overall looks great in your living room.

Another great suggestion is [Boxee](http://www.boxee.tv/make) which can be installed on top of Ubuntu similar to XMBC. Boxee is less configurable than XMBC, but offers great plugins with a fantastic beginning layout, and is a bit more simple to work with.

Lastly, if you don't need a pretty UI for your movies, you can just install Ubuntu as normal and use the [Medibuntu](http://medibuntu.org/) Repository to handle all of your media needs. This won't give you a nice skin like the previous two options, in fact it will be just like having a normal computer as a media center, but it contains a lot of great tools for that setup.

Also feel free to use any combination of the above suggestions, and play around with different setups. The links I provided are all great places to get started.

Answer (score 0):

XBMC - check it out [xbmc.org](http://xbmc.org/about/)

Comment: Could you add a little more information other than a [link](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/257/how-does-ask-ubuntu-work/542#542)